# Looking for event registration + appt booking plugin

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, registration

I’m looking for a Wordpress plugin that allows users to register for an event (networking event) and then these same users can book appointments within the platform so they can meet and greet.

I’m hoping the event registration form can be customizable allowing conditional logic.

I’ve looked into Amelia but the form registration it’s very limited.

Any other ideas? Thank you in advance!

Looked around Google, too many options and can’t find what I’m looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.